# Clear every other bit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bit-manipulation

How do I clear every other for a string in Ruby, and convert it to byte array? I understand that I need to do AND operation with 0x01010101 value for every byte. But the difficulty is with correct conversion from string to binary. Ideally it should be fast and with least amount of allocations.

Later I will need to pass this value to `Digest::MD5.hexdigest`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want because you're using contradictory language.  Could you try explaining it better?  An AND operation with 0x01010101 is definitely not the same as clearing every other bit, it would clear seven eighths of the bits.

Comment: @David, I find your comment about keeping the odd bit a bit odd, it part the bit about using `0x..` as a mask to keep every other bit, and also the bit about failing to clear one bit, considering that every leading zero bit clears the corresponding bit, even though it is only imaged. If I'm wrong, byte me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, note that `0x` is for base 16, `0b` is for base 2:

```
0b11111111.to_s(2) #=> "11111111"
0x11111111.to_s(2) #=> "10001000100010001000100010001"
```

As you are converting bits within bytes you want to use `0b...` for your mask.

Next,

```
0b01010101.to_s(2) #=> "1010101"
```

showing that, as with all integers, leading zeroes are dropped, meaning you can include them or not. Consider,

```
0b11111111 & 0     #=> 0
```

It is seen that, as a mask, zero is treated as having 7 leading bits of zero. We see that

```
(0b11111111 &
  0b1010101).to_s(2) #=> "1010101"
```

So, we can define your bitwise mask as

```
MASK = 0b1010101
```

We can now use [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-unpack1) with format string `"C*"` to convert the string to an array of 8-bit unsigned integers, which we then *bitwise and* with `MASK` (using `&`):

```
str = "Let's party, now!"
str.unpack("C*").map { |u| u & MASK }
  #=> [68, 69, 84, 5, 81, 0, 80, 65, 80, 84, 81, 4, 0, 68, 69, 85, 1]
```

The `"C"` in `"C*"` means the format directive `"C"` is applied to the first character; `"*"` means to repeat `"C"` for all subsequent characters.

See also [Integer#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-26).

I see from @DavidKling's answer that one could alternatively write

```
str.bytes.map { |u| u & MASK }
```

Comment: _"leading zeroes [...] you can include them or not"_ – it's the same value but as a reader I find a 7-bit binary digit quite confusing. I'd always write `0b01010101`. It also makes the digits align much nicer ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, I do something similar when writing cheques, but for a different reason: to impress the recipient with my generosity. For example, $0,000,000.99.

Comment: _Zero million zero thousand zero dollars and ninety-nine cents_

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#bytes` to give you an array of the string's characters' unicode values (in decimal).

```rb
 'Roman'.bytes # [82, 111, 109, 97, 110]
```

Comment: `bytes` returns the raw byte values. The string's Unicode values are returned by [`codepoints`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-codepoints). (which happen to be the same for the ASCII range)